# how to get AVG for all records in 2 tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I need to get AVG for every row in SQL for example:

this is the first table

```
+ ---+------+-------------+
| course_id | course_name | 
+ ----------+-------------+
| 1         | a           |
| 2         | b           | 
| 3         | c           | 
| 4         | g           | 
+ ---+------+-------------+
```

This is the second table 
I need to get AVG for both id 1 and 2. the result for example:

```
+ -------------------+------+----------+
| course_feedback_id | rate |course_id |
+ -================--+------+----------+
|       1            | 4    |   1      |
|       2            | 3    |   1      |
|       3            | 2    |   2      |
+ -------------------+------+----------+
```

this is the final answer that i need

```
+ ----------------------+
| course_id | AVG(rate) |
+ -=======--+-----------+
|     1     | 3.5       |   
|     2     | 2         |     
+ ----------------------+
```

I tried this soulution but it will give me only the first row not all records.

```
SELECT *, AVG(`rate`) from secondTable
```

please help

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select course_id, avg(rate) from table1,table2 where table1.course_id=table2.course_id group by course_id;
```

Comment: error : #1052 - Column 'course_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: it works if I select only course.course_id. but I need to merge to tables together and I need to select course_feedback_id it shows an error called #1052 - Column 'registration_reg_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Thank you very much I solve it by your answer but I just add the name of the table before the reg_id :)

Comment: I tried again it just show 2 records not all of them :(

Comment: `select table1.course_id,table2.course_feedback_id, avg(rate) from table1,table2 where table1.course_id=table2.course_id group by table1.course_id;`

Answer (score 0):

It's missing group by modifier

```
SELECT *, AVG(`rate`) 
  FROM secondTable 
  GROUP BY course_id
```

Comment: there is an error called :#1054 - Unknown column 'rate' in 'field list'